# Query regarding selenium webdriver

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium

I have a requirement like I need to launch say 50 threads and all threads will get a **headless Fire Fox instance** and do some operation as like login in a particular URL.

Currently when I am doing in my laptop having 2 GB RAM and Intel core i5 processor for many threads out of 50 it is **not able to get the firefox instance and throwing exception.**

When I will run on **Google cloud engine** having 300+GB RAM and many core, will I face the same issue there also?  Below is my code to get headless firefox instance.

```
String Xport = System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id", ":1");
            final File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path", "/usr/bin/firefox"));
            FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
            firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport);

            driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null);
```

This is the code to create threads,

```
Thread t=null; 
countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(totalNumberOfUsers); 
for(int i=1;i<=x;i++) { 
t=new Thread(new CasLoadTest()); 
allThreads.add(t); 
t.setName("Thread"+i); 
t.start(); 
Thread.sleep((long) (delayPeriod*1000)); 
} 
for(Thread thread : allThreads) { thread.join(); }
```

Comment: and how do you create those 50 threads?

Comment: Thread t=null;
   countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(totalNumberOfUsers);

   for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
   {
    t=new Thread(new CasLoadTest());
    allThreads.add(t);
    t.setName("Thread"+i);
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep((long) (delayPeriod*1000));
   }

   for(Thread thread : allThreads)
   {
    thread.join();
   }

Comment: always remember one thing best practise for parallel execution is numberOfThreads = numberOfCores - 1. so try instead 5 browsers instead of 50 and see if things work